# Retrieving data from database using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to get to grips with using JPA. And am extremely stuck. I am trying to retrieve data from a database to display on a form. I keep getting the following error and none of the information I have found online has helped:

> java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

The code where the error occurs is below:

```
try
    {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query q = em.createQuery("Select o from Order o");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Order> orders = q.getResultList();
        Iterator<Order> iterator = orders.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Order order = (Order)iterator.next();

            order.setId(this.id);
            order.setCreated(this.created);
            order.setSender(this.sender);
            order.setReceiver(this.receiver);
            order.setInput(this.input);
            order.setOutput(this.output);
            order.setState(this.state);
            orders.add(order);
        }
        em.persist(orders);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

Comment: You are modifying[orders.add(order);] the collection(orders) while performing iteraton. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html

Comment: Also, why are you trying to change the `id` of **all** the orders in your database? This will probably do something silly. 99% of the time, the primary key of an entity should not change during its lifetime. What is your code meant to accomplish?

Comment: Also, really, how did the documentation for [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) **not** explain the reason why you're getting it?

Comment: I thought it did and I thought I understood it so i implemented changes suggested on other forums and websites to solve it but nothing worked so i thought i must have been misunderstanding it. Hence coming to you guys for help as the people on SO always seem very knowledgable and helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add elements to a correction you're iterating over. (You're iterating over orders using orders.iterator(), and then you're trying to do orders.add(order) in the body of the iterator.)

The whole construct is useless anyway. Just change the properties of the objects in `orders`, and the changes will be saved to the database automagically when you `commit()` it. Last, but not least, you should use the extended `for` there.

```
for (Order order : (List<Order>) q.getResultList()) {
    order.setId(...);
    // ...
}
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Going by the comments, you're just trying to retrieve existing records from the database, not add or modify anything in it. In that case, you just need to return the result of `getResultList()` to the GUI:

```
return (List<Order>) q.getResultList();
```

without doing anything else with the entity manager after that call.

Comment: Just to clarify this is supposed to be retrieving data from the database not saving it to the database. And therefore the id will be set to a different id for each row as in the database

Comment: Am I doing this completely wrong to retrieve data? If so could you advise me as to the correct way?

Comment: Also if I use the code stated in your answer I get a type mismatch on q.getResultList() :(

Comment: @DannyBoy My bad, you just need to do the cast there then.

Comment: @DannyBoy Also, in your code you're not just retrieving data, you seem to be modifying it as well, in a highly suspect way. (Changing *every* `Order`, and modifying the `id`.) I can't tell you whether you're doing it wrong without  knowing what you're ultimately trying to accomplish. I.e. what the original contents of the database are, and what you want them to be after your code runs.

Comment: @DannyBoy If you're just trying to create a new `Order`, you don't need to query at all. Just do `Order order = new Order();`, set its properties, then `persist(order)` and `commit()`. But carefully following a tutorial would've told you that.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve all data from a database to display it in a GUI. The way I am trying to do it is the only way I could find. Unless, as I said I have got the wrong idea, but surely at some point a query needs to go to the database in order to retrieve the data

Comment: I have 1 table in the database. I am trying to retrieve all data within that database. Then I am trying to display it in a primefaces GUI. As far as I am aware, in order to do this, a query must be sent to the database to retrieve the data and then it must be stored in a list of the object in order to display it in a table. Or am I completely along the wrong lines with this?

Comment: @DannyBoy The list `orders` is already the list you need - JPA builds it for you correctly. Just pass it to your GUI directly. You shouldn't need to add anything to anything else in a loop.

Comment: orders is the list I need however, on the first load of the program, the list is empty. this method is supposed to be filling this list for me to pass it to the GUI

Comment: @DannyBoy Can't you just pre-fill the database when your application starts up? It seems like you're trying to do two things at once in a confusing way. Just do them separately - have the method that fetches data for the GUI do that and nothing else. And have another method **check** if the database is empty, and add items into the database if it is.

Comment: At no point in this method am I trying to add data to the database, I have a seperate method called addRow() for that. The database is an oracle database in SQL Developer which always has data in it. The problem i have is retrieving that data

Comment: @DannyBoy "at no point" - how about when you call `em.persist(order)` then? What are you then filling this list with - to me it seems like you're filling it with a bunch of dummy data, several copies of whatever is stored in the properties of `this`, which you then save to the DB. If your database contains data, and `getResultList()` returns an empty list, then your error is somewhere else.

Comment: So all I should need is: `factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
  EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager(); em.getTransaction().begin();
   Query q = em.createQuery("Select o from Order o");
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   List<Order> orders = q.getResultList(); em.persist(orders);
   em.getTransaction().commit();`??

Comment: The same error is displayed if I only use that code. Where else could the error be?

Comment: @DannyBoy I think you really need to go through the tutorials and the API docs a bit more, you seem to be throwing code at a wall here and seeing what sticks. To **retrieve** data from the database, you don't need `persist()` or `commit()`. Seeing as `persist()` persists (i.e. *saves*) new entities into the entity manager; and `commit()` commits these new entities, as well as changes to old entities retrieves through this entity manager into the database. When retrieving, you just make a query, and use the return value of `getResultList()` directly.

Comment: @DannyBoy Is it the same error from the same location? Because when you remove your `for` loop, there's no reason for a `ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown. You should edit your question to include what code you have now and what error it gives you, including the stacktrace and where in your code sample the line numbers in it refer to.

Comment: Thank you. Taking out the transaction parts and the persist worked. I must really not understand this as much as I thought I did. It is now working as expected but I will read more documentation before I continue. Can you recommend any decent places? Also if you want to put that in an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through a list while adding to it which is causing the issue.

`orders.add(order);`

Create a new list and add orders to that, then persist that new list.

Comment: Ok. Sorry Im fairly new to JPA etc. I have created the list orders just above the iteration. Where should I create a new list and where should I add to it?

Comment: Create a new list before the while loop

Comment: This isn't a JPA issue as much as a general Java issue.  Create the new list before you start the loop.

Comment: `List<Order> orders = q.getResultList();
   List<Order> orders2 = null;
   Iterator<Order> iterator = orders.iterator();
   while(iterator.hasNext())
   {
    Order order = (Order)iterator.next();
    
    order.setId(this.id);
    order.setCreated(this.created);
    order.setSender(this.sender);
    order.setReceiver(this.receiver);
    order.setInput(this.input);
    order.setOutput(this.output);
    order.setState(this.state);
    orders2.add(order);
   }
   em.persist(orders2);`

Comment: yes, apart from create a new instance of ArrayList or it'll throw a NPE.

Comment: I have changed `List<Order> orders2=null;` to `ArrayList<Order> orders2=null;` and I get a NPE on the line `orders2.add(order);`

Comment: Do `List<Order> orders2 = new new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I have also tried changing it to `List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<Order>();`. In that instance I get the following error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: [com.ProEJT.Order@1e41869, com.ProEJT.Order@1feae0f, com.ProEJT.Order@1556f4c, com.ProEJT.Order@1fe0816, com.ProEJT.Order@c50561, com.ProEJT.Order@4c9c17, com.ProEJT.Order@19bdb65, com.ProEJT.Order@160e796, com.ProEJT.Order@1046822, com.ProEJT.Order@509bfc, com.ProEJT.Order@30cefd, com.ProEJT.Order@65724d, com.ProEJT.Order@333b2e] is not a known entity type.`

Comment: This is a separate issue altogether, you need to mark the Order entity as @Entity with that annotation.

Comment: I have done `@Entity
@Table(name="Orders")
public class Order
{`

Comment: Then somewhere you're not scanning for this object.  Either way, this is a totally different issue.

Comment: I have created a new question for this issue. If you could take a look if you get chance [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385101/jpa-object-is-not-a-known-entity-type)