# JPA Object [] is not a known entity type

Tags: java, jpa

I have a JPA in which I am trying to retrieve data from an Oracle database. I get the following error when I load the page:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: [com.ProEJT.Order@1f7be7b, com.ProEJT.Order@1fa8988, com.ProEJT.Order@15b44d6, com.ProEJT.Order@1044daf, com.ProEJT.Order@1882d18, com.ProEJT.Order@389922, com.ProEJT.Order@1cda81e, com.ProEJT.Order@d86c58, com.ProEJT.Order@b1404f, com.ProEJT.Order@f5331a, com.ProEJT.Order@1ee145b, com.ProEJT.Order@17a687b, com.ProEJT.Order@16181be, com.ProEJT.Order@8d12e4, com.ProEJT.Order@1d35bf2, com.ProEJT.Order@1398044, com.ProEJT.Order@141d19, com.ProEJT.Order@825459, com.ProEJT.Order@6fb3d6, com.ProEJT.Order@1602bbc, com.ProEJT.Order@d75cf7, com.ProEJT.Order@1186cf9] is not a known entity type.

My only entity class is Order:

```
package com.ProEJT;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity(name="Orders")
@Table(name="Orders")
public class Order
{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
int id;
private Date created;
private String sender;
private String receiver;
private String input;
private String output;
private String state;

public Order() {

}

public Order(int id, Date date, String sender, String receiver, String input, String output, String state)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.created = date;
    this.sender = sender;
    this.receiver = receiver;
    this.input = input;
    this.output = output;
    this.state = state;
}

public int getId() 
{
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) 
{
    this.id = id;
}

public Date getCreated() 
{
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(Date date) 
{
    this.created = date;
}

public String getSender() 
{
    return sender;
}

public void setSender(String sender) 
{
    this.sender = sender;
}

public String getReceiver() 
{
    return receiver;
}

public void setReceiver(String receiver) 
{
    this.receiver = receiver;
}

public String getInput() 
{
    return input;
}

public void setInput(String string) 
{
    this.input = string;
}

public String getOutput() 
{
    return output;
}

public void setOutput(String string) 
{
    this.output = string;
}

public String getState() 
{
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) 
{
    this.state = state;
}
}
```

The method I use to retrieve the data is as follows:

```
public List<Order> getOrderList()
{
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
    try
    {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query q = em.createQuery("Select o from Orders o");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Order> orders = q.getResultList();
        List<Order> orders2 = new ArrayList<Order>();
        Iterator<Order> iterator = orders.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Order order = (Order)iterator.next();

            order.setId(this.id);
            order.setCreated(this.created);
            order.setSender(this.sender);
            order.setReceiver(this.receiver);
            order.setInput(this.input);
            order.setOutput(this.output);
            order.setState(this.state);
            orders2.add(order);
        }
        em.persist(orders2);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        em.close();
    }   
    return orders;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

METHOD TAKE 2:

```
public List<Order> getOrderList()
{
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query q = em.createQuery("Select o from Order o");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Order> orders = q.getResultList();
        em.persist(orders);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    return orders;
}
```

Comment: Invoking the `persist` method just "saves" your instance in the database. In your case, the variable `orders` already contains all the `Order` instances that you have just retrieved from the db using `q.getResultList()`. Why are you trying to save them again?

Comment: The call to persist is redundant ... the objects retrieved from a query are MANAGED, hence any update will be persisted directly without the need to call persist. Covered in any decent JPA book or documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't persist whole `orders2`, because `ArrayList` is not JPA aware class. Probably you should persist each element inside loop:

```
        while(iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Order order = (Order)iterator.next();

            order.setId(this.id);
            order.setCreated(this.created);
            order.setSender(this.sender);
            order.setReceiver(this.receiver);
            order.setInput(this.input);
            order.setOutput(this.output);
            order.setState(this.state);
            orders2.add(order);
            em.persist(order);
        }
```

Comment: I have now edited my code and will edit in the question. I was advised that I didnt need the iteration at all so I will add the new method into my question

Comment: Why do you call `em.persist(orders);` in this case?

Comment: I have realised my understanding of JPA was a little off so ive now sorted it and the error has gone. thank you